# requests.put don't update spreadsheet

Tags: python, google-sheets, put

I'm trying to update rows in a spreadsheet (see annex) with the help of Sheety. I want the column "IATA Code" filled with cell values "TESTING". When I run the code it gives me no errors but it won't update the spreadsheet. Why wouldn't it update the spreadsheet?

```
import requests

API_KEY_GET = "my_key_for_get"
API_KEY_PUT = "my_key_for_put (without [Object ID]"
TELLER = 2

response = requests.get(url=API_KEY_GET)
response.raise_for_status()
data = response.json()
sheet_data = [p for p in data["prices"]]

for iat in sheet_data:
    iat["iataCode"] = "TESTING"

for i in sheet_data:
    sht_inputs = {
        "price": {
            "City": i["city"],
            "IATA Code": i["iataCode"],
            "Lowest Price": i["lowestPrice"]
        }
    }
    sht_response = requests.put(url=f"{API_KEY_PUT}{TELLER}", json=sht_inputs)
    TELLER += 1
    sht_response.raise_for_status()
```

I tried a new project in Sheety with different names. The spreadsheet won't update either
I tried post instead of put. If I post to add a row the spreadsheet won't update either.

Comment: I found the issue: I wrote "IATA Code". This must be replaced with "iataCode".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue for this one.
This is my solution:

```
import requests

FLIGHT_URL = "https://api.tequila.kiwi.com/locations/query"
FLIGHT_API = "kwncSx7gdoQSIjBQ8_yyVyrNcCkq3wuW"
CITIES = ["Paris", "Berlin", "Tokyo", "Sydney", "Istanbul", "New York", "Kuala Lumpur", "San Francisco", "Cape Town"]

SHEETY_URL = "https://api.sheety.co/047bf28f7ad1b00e907d155576a1d720/myFlightDeals/flights"
row_id = 2

for item in CITIES:
    flight_parameters = {
        "term": item
    }
    flight_header = {
        "apikey": FLIGHT_API
    }
    response_flight = requests.get(url=FLIGHT_URL, params=flight_parameters, headers=flight_header)
    code = response_flight.json()["locations"][0]["code"]

    sheety_parameters = {
        "flight": {
            "iataCode": code,
        }
    }

    response_sheety = requests.put(url=f"{SHEETY_URL}/{row_id}", json=sheety_parameters)
    row_id += 1
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Sheety uses camelCase, therefore you'll have to re-arrange the column names in your json dictionary:

```
sht_inputs = {
    "price": {
        "city": i["city"],
        "iataCode": i["iataCode"],
        "lowestPrice": i["lowestPrice"]
    }
}
```